# Windows Service Best Loop Way?

Tags: sql-server, windows, loops, service

I need a windows service to transfer data to another SQL server every 10 minutes.
This service is scheduled with a periodicity of 10 minutes and executes 5 stored procedures that transfer the data

If machine restarts the service should work again.

So, What's best way for this service?

My solution is as below. But this service will stop after the first time:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

#if DEBUG

        Service1 myService = new Service1();
        myService.OnDebug();

#else

        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);

#endif

    }


public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Thread _worker;
    static readonly AutoResetEvent StopRequest = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static IDataRepository _dataRepository;

    public Service1()
    {
        _dataRepository = new DataRepository();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _worker = new Thread(DoWork);
        _worker.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopRequest.Set();
        _worker.Join();
    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!_dataRepository.CheckInternetConnection()) return;
            if (!_dataRepository.CheckDatabaseConnection()) return;
            if (!_dataRepository.CheckOppositeDatabaseConnection()) return;
            if (StopRequest.WaitOne(10000)) return;
            List<Test> comeResults = _dataRepository.CheckNewDataCashRegister();
            if (comeResults == null) return;
            bool sendTest = _dataRepository.SendTest(comeResults);
            if (!sendTest) return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd just create an executable an let Windows Task Scheduler do the looping. That's way easier and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. How can i create task scheduler for this project?

Comment: Just type "Task Scheduler" on your Windows Start Screen or follow [Start Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931.aspx) and look into [Task Scheduler on MS TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871%28v=ws.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize external dependencies like using the Task Scheduler you can schedule the work in the service like this:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private static IDataRepository _dataRepository;

    public Service1()
    {
        _dataRepository = new DataRepository();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ScheduleWorkAsync();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
         _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
         _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    private async Task ScheduleWorkAsync()
    {
        var _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                DoWork();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), _cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        if (!_dataRepository.CheckInternetConnection()) return;
        if (!_dataRepository.CheckDatabaseConnection()) return;
        if (!_dataRepository.CheckOppositeDatabaseConnection()) return;

        List<Test> comeResults = _dataRepository.CheckNewDataCashRegister();
        if (comeResults == null) return;
        bool sendTest = _dataRepository.SendTest(comeResults);
        if (!sendTest) return;
    }       
}
```